# Menus not working when external monitor connected

Tags: unity, display, hdmi, external-monitor

When I have an external monitor connected, *certain* programs show an annoying behaviour, which is that their **menus don't expand on hover**.

With this I mean that, when I click an item on the menu bar (let's say, `File` in Firefox, and the File menu expands), and then move and hover over to the next item (`Edit`), the Edit menu does not expand, until I click on it.

It seems that only **maximised** programs **on the external monitor** are affected.

More verbose / further observations:

- The problem does not present itself on programs that are 'windowed' (i.e., not maximised). On those windowed programs, the menu items do expand, be it a bit laggy, even if they are on the external monitor.
- The problem does not present itself on the laptop screen (even if maximised), and regardless of whether or not the external monitor is connected.
- The menus of the items in the indicator menu bar (clock, wifi symbol, sound volume, bluetooth, input language, etc) show the same behaviour, of not expanding on the external monitor.
- Changing the location of the menus from 'menu bar' to 'window's title bar', or changing the visibility of the menus from 'displayed on mouse hovering' to 'always displayed' (in Settings >> Appearance >> Behavior) has no effect.

A reboot of the system doesn't fix it.

Any idea how to fix this?

My setup: **Dell xps 13 kaby lake**, external monitor over HDMI through usb-c adapter. **Ubuntu 16.10 unity**, up to date. The external monitor is the primary display (i.e., the screens are not mirrored).

Many thanks!

Comment: Is your _mirror display options selected_ ?

Comment: no; i'm extending the desktop to use both screens (laptop and external)

Comment: Enabling that option wouldn't help ? Never used it though .

Comment: Take a look at this _[display setup guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/configuring-monitor-ubuntu/)_ for ubuntu

Comment: Thanks @George for the suggestion. I've had a look, but there's nothing there to help me. Mirroring the display options only has the effect of showing the same content on both screens.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you set the screen resolutions to be the same on both monitors? I suspect that the problem may be with your HDMI through usb-c adapter... not a hardware problem... a compatibility issue.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference. I found that it's only affecting maximised programs, though - I've updated the question

Comment: Hmmmm.... no other suggestions!?